# Searching a text file backwards from the end

Tags: c, linux, performance, file

I'm trying to find the string containing the substring in a text file by starting at the end. The file has tens of millions of lines.
(The requirement is to read from End of the File. I cannot use sed/awk/grep etc)

The below program does the job but it takes a long time. How can I make it run faster?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strrev(char *str)
{
      char *p1, *p2;

      if (! str || ! *str)
            return str;
      for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
      {
            *p1 ^= *p2;
            *p2 ^= *p1;
            *p1 ^= *p2;
      }
      return str;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *fd;
        char len[100];

        int ch,count;
        int fpos=0;

        char *filename = argv[1];

        fd = fopen(filename, "r");
        fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        fpos = ftell(fd);

        while (fpos > 0)
        {
                fseek(fd, -2, SEEK_CUR);
                if(ftell(fd) <= 2)
                        break;

                ch = fgetc(fd);
                fpos--;
                count = 0;
                memset( len, 0, sizeof(len));
                while(ch != '\n')
                {
                        len[count++] = ch;
                        if(ftell(fd) < 2)
                                break;
                        fseek(fd, -2, SEEK_CUR);
                        ch =fgetc(fd);
                }
                strrev(len);
                if( strstr(len,"TEST") !=NULL )
                {
                        printf("Found test. \n");
                        break;
                }
                //if(found)
                //do other stuff
        } 
        fclose(fd);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could read large chunks of text using `fread`.

Comment: How to read a complete line when we are reading the file from EOF?

Comment: Reading char by char using `fgetc`, `ftell` and `fseek` for each and every char in the file is definitely very inefficient.

Comment: And also calling `strrev` for every line is inefficient. Also the "clever" xor swap thingy is inefficient. You should roll out your own "strstr" that searches directly a reversed string. But anyway if you read large chunks of text, you don't even need to reverse anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by commentators, doing IO one character at a time (+ fseek + ftell) is very expensive. Remember that each time the code `fgets` the first character, the C library will 'read ahead' - reading BUFSIZ characters.

As an alternative, consider 'read before' logic, based on ideas provided above.

- find out length of pattern `pl`
- Allocate a buffer size of `bs`
- Read blocks of bs backward. Each block will overlap with previous block for `pl` characters, eliminating the possibility that a match will occur in between blocks.
- Assuming bs much larger the pl, cost of overlap reads is minimal, and performance close to optimal.

Error checks reduced to keep code clear.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define   BS 100000
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if ( !fp ) { perror("fopen") ; exit (1) ; };

   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) ;
   long pos = ftell(fp) ;
   fprintf(stderr, "S=%ld\n", pos) ;

   const char *pattern = argv[2] ;
   const int PL = strlen(pattern) ;

       // Read backward
   char buff[BS+1] ;
   long match = -1;
   while ( pos > 0 ) {
       pos = pos - (BS-PL) ;
       if ( pos < 0 ) pos = 0 ;
       fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET) ;
       int n = fread(buff, sizeof(buff[0]), BS, fp) ;
       if ( n > 0 ) {
           buff[n] = 0 ;
           char *loc = strstr(buff, pattern) ;
           if ( loc ) ) { match = pos + (loc-buff) ; break ;} ;
       } ;
   } ;
   fclose(fp) ;
   printf("MATCH=%ld\n", match) ;
}
```

Note that solution will only handle TEXT files. The 'strstr' will NOT work on data loaded from binary file which may contain NUL characters.

Updated 2019-11-12 to correct file position calculation when match is in first block.

Comment: Thanks @dash-o. How do i get the exact fp position . i.e. after the line the pattern match is found. I think i'm getting the fp position at the block start.

Comment: Are there any other requirements ? Posted update to calculate exact offset of the match, based on the block start, and relative position in buffer. Please test - I'm away from computer

Comment: Thanks. It works for large file , I havent completely tested it. But for smaller files i see the fp position to be wrong. I guess we need to handle -ve condition.

Comment: @m4n07 corrected file position calculation for match in the first block of the  file.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer if it addressed your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to count the lines ,after finding the match using this code          for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         {
            if( (ch == '\n'))
            {
               lineCount++;
           }
            ch = buff[i];
         }                                                                                                                                   But for some reasons its showing different count in case of large files.

Comment: In other words you can say that I replaced this part of code with  the one in my above comment. For line counting,                          
        if ( n > 0 ) {
           buff[n] = 0 ;
           char *loc = strstr(buff, pattern) ;
           if ( loc ) ) { match = pos + (loc-buff) ; break ;} ;
       } ;

Comment: The file is split into blocks with overlap, so that it will not miss a line.I did not know you need a line count. To get the correct line count, you need to look i from 0 to max(n, BS-PL) for anything but the last block. Also note that the a match for the string will stop reading earlier blocks (with the break statement), the linecount may not include all blocks

Comment: Given search in reverse, I assume that you want to limit backward search to <N> lines. Is this a hard limit (search in the last N lines), or "soft" (no need to search beyond N lines)  ? Are you trying to implement `tail -N large-file | grep -q string` ?

Comment: I tried commenting the pattern search if block and added the code for line counting for a large file to stop at counting of 100000. Then i printed the first line after that position, I see a difference of 300 lines.

Comment: The logic is correct, but need some tuning to handle the reading of 'overlap' region - which helped with efficiency. Give me some time to think on what change is needed to your code to fit into the block loop.

Comment: I'm able to fix it after updating the position in the newly added loop.